# having problems packaging my game in UE 5.3.2

Tags: game-development, packaging, unreal-engine5, blueprint

Hello brilliant minds you are my only hope left.

I am unsure how to proceed any further. It was a week ago or so that I started trying to package my game in 5.3.2 but that didnt work. Upon investigation, I discovered that when I use a game instance upon reopening the UE editor, it crashes. So i have been working very hard to replace game instance with save game. But tonight just for kicks. I tried to package my, without game instance. And the same cryptic error that happens every when the game instance crashes the editor happened in package.

I had thought this error is caused by presence of game instance so i was just testing to see ok what if there is no game instance would my game package, sadly the answer is NO.

both my crash log and the package error log share the same cryptic error whose meaning have not been able to find in all my searches online.

The error shared is:

Assertion failed: Linker [File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp] [Line: 2152]

So I went and downloaded the debugging symbols. so this time the package failing log is much more explicit, here is the complete log.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALs09cpq9AXe7RX7KE2abcDT6Ipz6sbe/view?usp=drive_link

the full crash log after using game instance upon reopening the ue editor is
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NuOuLOSsQCy0sIIX6u076dlEuR5__5gihrbVuSjla6w/edit

thanks you so much for all the help, guidance and tips you would have in this matter. thanks!

I have tried to package my game and it doesnt work

Comment: Try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: So I went and downloaded the debugging symbols. so this time the package failing log is much more explicit, here is the complete log.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALs09cpq9AXe7RX7KE2abcDT6Ipz6sbe/view?usp=drive_link